# How do I save file with dialog?

Tags: c#

I'm trying save the print screen with the code below but it doesn' t work

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            button1.Visible = false;
            button2.Visible = false;
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
            this.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, this.ClientRectangle);
            bitmap.Save("myPrintScreen.bmp");
            button1.Visible = true;
            button2.Visible = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx . look at that, example included

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/savefiledialog

Comment: @illDev Because of no research effort. Try to google your very own title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx)

```
 SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
 if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {
     // Save file, use saveFileDialog1.FileName
 }
```

You can set the filename with the `Filename` [Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx). For your example:

```
saveFileDialog1.FileName = "myPrintScreen.bmp";
```

[Edit after question edit]
Change

```
this.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, this.ClientRectangle);
```

to:

```
using(var Stream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile())
{
    bitmap.Save(Stream , ImageFormat.Bmp);
}
```

Comment: and where I set the file? ` SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
 if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {
 button1.Visible = false;
        button2.Visible = false;
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
        this.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, this.ClientRectangle);
        bitmap.Save("myPrintScreen.bmp");
        button1.Visible = true;
        button2.Visible = true;
 }`?

Comment: you can set the filename before you call `.OpenDialog()`

Comment: `private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.FileName = "myPrintScreen.bmp";
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {  button1.Visible = false; button2.Visible = false;
  Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
                using (var Stream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile())
                {
                    bitmap.Save(Stream, bitmap.bmp);
                }                button1.Visible = true;
                button2.Visible = true;
            }}`

Comment: `bitmap.Save(Stream, bitmap.bmp);` should be `bitmap.Save(Stream , ImageFormat.Bmp);`

Comment: then I'm getting 'The name 'ImageFormat' does not exist in the current context'

Comment: bitmap.Save(Stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp); It works! thx a lot

Comment: Because you deleted the line `this.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, this.ClientRectangle);`

Comment: @boindiil How can I convert the bitmap to pdf?

Answer (score 1):

You need the [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx).
Take a look at the example provided there.